# Check if polynomial is subtraction free

Tags: polynomials

I have several very long, factorised polynomials in several variables, e.g.

```
x1^4 x2^3 x3 x4^3 x5 x6 x7^2 x8 (1 + x2 + x2 x3 + x5 + x1 x5)
```

I want an easy way to check whether such a polynomial is 'subtraction free' in the sense of having no relative minus sign between terms anywhere. So

```
-x1(1+x2+x2*x3)
```

or

```
x1*x2+1+x3+x4*x5)
```

are both fine, but

```
x1*x2(1+x1*x3-x2)
```

is not.

Is there any easy way to implement this?

Comment: What answer would you seek if the polynomial had the form `-((-x - y) z)`? I ask since you specified a "factorised polynomial", and I wasn't sure if that meant it shouldn't be multiplied out.

Comment: Maybe "relative minus sign" means no nonzero monomials in a factor with opposite signs?

Comment: Are the coefficients always integers (with head `Integer`)?

Comment: -(-x-y)z would count as subtraction-free, yes. Rather than 'factorised polynomial' one could just expand out the whole thing and seek no relative minus signs between terms. The coefficients in my application would all be integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expressions:

```
t1 = x1x2 (1 + x1x3 - x2);
t2 = -x1 (1 + x2 + x2x3);
```

should be bad/good. For this look at the FullForm of t1/t2:

```
t1//FullForm
t2//FullForm
```

[image]

[image]

Note the position of "-1":

Position[t1, -1]

Position[t2, -1]

```
{{2, 3, 1}}
{{1}}
```

If -1 is on level 1 it is good like in t2. In t1 -1 is deeper nested. We may exploit this lik3 e.g.:

```
check[ex_] := Length[Position[ex, -1][[1]]] <= 1
```

With this:

```
check[t1]
check[t2]

False
True
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like:

```
f1 = FreeQ[Factor @ #, Plus[_?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ, __]] &;

f2 = FreeQ[Factor @ #, Times[_?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ, __], {1, ∞}] & ;
```

***Examples:***

```
expr1 = x1^4 x2^3 x3 x4^3 x5 x6 x7^2 x8 (1 + x2 + x2 x3 + x5 + x1 x5);

expr2 = - x1^4 x2^3 x3 x4^3 x5 x6 x7^2 x8 (1 + x2 + x2 x3 + x5 + x1 x5);

expr3 = x1^4 x2^3 x3 x4^3 x5 x6 x7^2 x8 (1 + x2 + x2 x3 - x5 +  x1 x5);


f1 /@ {expr1, expr2, expr3}
```

> ```
> {True, True, False}
> ```

```
f2 /@ {expr1, expr2, expr3}
```

> ```
> {True, True, False}
> ```

Comment: `expr2` seems to have a negative sign?

Comment: @Syed, yes. _**"So `-x1(1+x2+x2x3) ` and `x1*x2+1+x3+x4*x5)` are both fine"**_

Comment: I need to put glasses back on.

Comment: I wonder if the output of `f2[x1*x2 (1 + x1*x3 - 2 x2)]` is correct? I'd expect coefficients other than -1, 0, +1 could occur, even though they are missing from the OP.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelE2; updated with a fix.